# Why isn't my webpage running React.js nor JSX with the CDNs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

So I've been learning React and I'm trying to add it to a webpage that I'm working on. But whenever I try to use React or JSX code, nothing happens. The browser doesn't even acknowledge it. Here's my `index.html` and `index.js` code. 
 
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Experimental Website</title>

        <!-- CSS file link -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
        <h2 id="test"></h2>

        <!-- React.js CDN links -->
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

        <!-- Babel (remove later) -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

        <!-- JavaScript file link -->
        <src type="text/babel" src="index.js"></src>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react';

let testVariable = <h2>Help me</h2>;

ReactDOM.render(
    testVariable,
    document.getElementById("test")
);
```

What am I doing wrong? Why won't React run in the browser?

Comment: this will help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 how?

Comment: @Yatrix by introducing modular programming in JavaScript. `import` statement will cause errors in this context

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 the idea is for your comment to help and posting a link without context doesn't accomplish that. It's better to provide guidance, not just "read this".

Comment: @Yatrix "Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question ..." - [When should I comment? section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - , I'm pretty sure that the `import` statement will cause an error in the console & the article I posted simply helps viewers put 2 and 2 together. A more robust explanation (other than what I just gave) should be considered as an answer.

Comment: You linked to the topic of modules, not a section or a comment like, "you can't use import because..." then linked. You just posted the full page on modules. I suppose it's better than a link to google, so there's that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked.

```
// index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Experimental Website</title>

        <!-- CSS file link -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
        <div id="test"></div>

        <!-- React.js CDN links -->
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

        <!-- Babel (remove later) -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

        <!-- JavaScript file link -->
        <!-- you had <src> here -->
        <script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and,

```
// index.js
let testVariable = <h2>Help me</h2>;

ReactDOM.render(testVariable, document.getElementById('test'))
```

So, you had `<src>` instead of `<script>` and you were also using imports without modules. Linking the library injects a global `React` and `ReactDOM` object, so you're good to go there.

Happy coding!

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This ended up working. I think my problem was the two import lines because I had tried it in other files without that `<src>` typo. Thanks again!